# Is there a function to run all possible combinations of values for multiple variables?

Tags: r

Apologies if I'm missing an existing function that does this, but struggling to find something.

Basically I have an example like follows (keeping it generic):

```
function <- (var1, var2)
values_for_var1 <- c("a", "b", "c")
values_for_var2 <- c(1:5)
```

What I'm wondering is if there is a quick function that would enable me to 'feed' in the two vectors listed to `var1` and `var2` respectively, and run this for all possible pairings? Eg, run the function where `var1 == "a"` for `var2 == 1`, then `var2 == 2`, then `var2 == 3`, etc, and repeat for `var1 == "b"` amd `var2 == c`.

Could do it the 'long-way' round but this doesn't scale very well with many variables or possible values for said variables. I thought `purrr` may have something but unless I'm misreading the guidance it doesn't do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) expand.grid** `expand.grid` will give all combinations of its arguments in a grid data frame `g`. Then we can operate over the rows of g.

Note that `expand.grid` will convert character inputs into factors by default unless `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` is specified as an argument to it.

An alternative to `expand.grid` is `merge` but it is limited to two arguments whereas `expand.grid` will work with any number.

```
# inputs
var1 <- letters[1:3]
var2 <- 1:5
f <- function(let, num) paste(10 * num, let)

# create grid
g <- expand.grid(var1, var2)

# operate on each row of grid

do.call(mapply, c("f", unname(as.list(g))))
# or
sapply(1:nrow(g), function(i) do.call("f", unname(g[i, ])))
# or
mapply(f, g[, 1], g[, 2])
```

These also work (or can be adapted in the case of the last one) for more than 2 vectors with functions having the same number of arguments.

**2) outer** For just 2 variables (as we have here) another approach is to use outer.  This produces a length(var1) by length(var2) matrix.  Note that outer only works with vectorized functions so it is common to write it like this:

```
outer(var1, var2, Vectorize(f))
```

**3) Comprehensions**

There are three packages on CRAN that support Python-like comprehensions with possibly modified syntax.

**3a) eList**

```
library(eList)
Chr(for(v1 in var1) for(v2 in var2) f(v1, v2))
```

If the result were numeric use Num in place of Chr or if it were a complex object use List.

**3b) listcompr**

```
library(listcompr)

n1 <- length(var1); n2 <- length(var2)
gen.vector.char("{ f(var1[i], var2[j]) }", i = 1:n1, j = 1:n2)
```

If the result were numeric use `gen.vector` instead of `gen.vector.char` and don't use the quotes or brace brackets.

**3c) comprehenr**

```
library(comprehenr)
to_vec(for (v1 in var1) for(v2 in var2) f(v1, v2))
```

**4) Other**  Some packages have alternatives to expand.grid and then we could use the facilities of that package to apply f or reproduce it natively.

**4a) dplyr/tidyr**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
crossing(var1, var2) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(result = f(var1, var2)) %>%
  ungroup
```

**4b) data.table**

```
library(data.table)
outDT <- CJ(var1, var2)[, result := f(var1, var2), by = .I]
```

**4c) sqldf**

```
library(sqldf)
var1df <- data.frame(var1); var2df <- data.frame(var2)
sqldf("select (10 * var2) || ' ' || var1 from var1df, var2df")
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can do `expand.grid` + `Vectorize` like below

```
with(
  expand.grid(values_for_var1, values_for_var2),
  Vectorize(func)(Var1, Var2)
)
```